# EL Capitan 10.11.4 Unknown Login Items

Tags: macos, login-items

I have this unknown item in my Login Items

How can i view what this is?
Not looking to remove just want to know what exact it is

[image]

Comment: This has happened to me before, and it always has been that the item is missing. That is my guess on what happened to you. In my opinion, this is in fact not a duplicate, considering that the other question days "Document," whereas this says "Unknown."

Comment: Thank you also here item name is missing too and in that other article item name is clear

Comment: The data is stored in the same place - it doesn't matter what the text says - the answer to both questions are going to be the same.